# Using pre-defined arguments for TikZ paths leads to an error

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys

While writing a small library to automate some path-drawing functions, I noticed that using defined arguments to replace hard-coded TikZ path options returns an error. Since I'm using the `\def` command to share common, user-given arguments between functions, this is hindering me quite a bit.

Here is a small MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[circle,draw] (example1) at (0,0) {1};
        \node[circle,draw] (example2) at (1,0) {2};

        % this works as expected
        \draw (example1) to [out=20,in=160] (example2);
        % this doesn't work
        \def\pathArguments{out=340,in=200}
        \typeout{\pathArguments} % returns 'out=340,in=200', as expected
        \draw (example1) to [\pathArguments] (example2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Expected output:

[image: expected output]

Actual output:

[image]

Error: `line 12: Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/out=340,in=200' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it. ... (example1) to [\pathArguments] (example2)`

I've even added a typeout to check if maybe the `\pathArguments` get modified in any way, but if one were to simply copy the result of the typeout in the square brackets instead of `\pathArguments`, the output is as expected.

Comment: Just remembered I'd answered basically the same question before: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300330/cant-use-macro-in-square-brackets/300382#300382

Comment: That is strikingly similar, yes. Thanks for your answer and the link, I've flagged this as a duplicate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `style` instead.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pathArguments/.style={out=340,in=200}]
        \node[circle,draw] (example1) at (0,0) {1};
        \node[circle,draw] (example2) at (1,0) {2};

        % this works as expected
        \draw (example1) to [out=20,in=160] (example2);
        % this works as well
        \draw (example1) to [pathArguments] (example2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Might be worth a word as to why this happens.  It's due to the comma in the macro.  pgfkeys splits its argument on commas and then processes each bit in turn.  It does the splitting *before* it tries to expand any macros, so in this case it passes `pathArguments` to the key processor which then expands it as a single key.  That is, it thinks that `out=20,in=160` is a whole key (I think it also looks for equals signs before expansion).  The correct way to package multiple keys is, as you say, via styles.